# Dynamic URL Refresh Rendering Issue in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

we are facing an issue with rendering when refreshing a dynamic URL in a React JS application using the catch-all approach. You can find the original approach we are following in [React-router URLs don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually).

On the server side, we are using the Java code with the Spark Java framework:

```
get("/*", (req, res) -> {
    String requestUri = req.uri();
    logger.info("requestUri=" + requestUri);
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
    return new ModelAndView(model, "/index.html");
}, new ReactEngine());
```

On the React side, we define the URL to the page using NavLink:

```
<NavLink
    to={`${ACTIVATE_ITEM_ROUTE_PREFIX}/${props.dataItem.id}`}
    title="Activate Item"
    className={props.dataItem.status !== "AVAILABLE" ? 'disabled':'' }
    style={props.dataItem.status !== "AVAILABLE" ? {pointerEvents: "none"} : null}
>
```

Here, `ACTIVATE_ITEM_ROUTE_PREFIX` is specified as:

```
export const ACTIVATE_ITEM_ROUTE_PREFIX = "/itemization/activate";
```

We then construct the full route:

```
export const ACTIVATE_ITEM_ROUTE = ACTIVATE_ITEM_ROUTE_PREFIX + "/" + 
    ROUTE_ID_PLACE_HOLDER;
```

Finally, we have a route defined in `App.js`:

```
<Route path={ACTIVATE_ITEM_ROUTE} component={ActivateItem} />
```

The catch-all approach works fine during initialization when the `requestUri` is "/", and it also works when `requestUri` is "/itemization-dashboard."

However, when we refresh the URL `http://localhost:8080/itemization/activate/12098`, we get the `requestUri` as "/itemization/activate/12098," but the rendering does not occur as expected.

We would appreciate suggestions to resolve this rendering issue when refreshing dynamic URLs in our React JS application.